# Consulta a una Tabla devuelve el título del campo del cual quiero sacar valores

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Este es mi primer post en la página. Pido disculpas de antemano si la pregunta resulta súper obvia o tonta, estoy empezando en esto.

Estoy haciendo consultas e inserciones a una base de datos, trabajo con PHP (versión 5.6 para abajo) y SQL. Estoy elaborando una cesta en la que guardar listas de compras, el aspecto es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me están pidiendo que guarde el idCesta de la última cesta generada. Para ello he probado consultas como las siguientes:

```
SELECT LAST_CURRENT_ID('IdCesta') FROM tabla_cesta
```

El error es:

> SELECT LAST_CURRENT_ID('IdCesta') FROM tabla_cesta LIMIT 0, 25

```
SELECT MAX('IdCesta') FROM tabla
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí no da error, pero me devuelve el nombre del campo!!! Siendo el tipo del campo INT(11)

¿Cómo puedo sacar el valor más grande del campo IdCesta? ¿Qué consulta he de hacer?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: Sí. Estoy trabajando con una versión antigua de PHP y no todas las soluciones que encontraba me valían. Entiendo que esto es algo súper obvio y puede resultar algo que se solucione fácilmente. De todas formas quería probar cómo es preguntar por aquí. Gracias por la aclaración. Un saludo!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente te sobran las comillas, por eso te aparece el nombre del campo:

```
SELECT MAX(IdCesta) FROM tabla;
```

Si tu campo incluyera algún espacio, tendrías que utilizar este otro tipo de comillas: `

Las de tipo " o ' son para delimitar el contenido de los campos.

Si estás utilizando PHP, también puedes hacer uso de la propiedad:

```
$ultimo_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Así, tras el `INSERT`, evitas tener que lanzar otra query al servidor

Comment: Patinada de novatazo, de verdad.... Muchísimas gracias por tu aportación! Especialmente por la última recomendación de la respuesta. Me la apunto!

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta @MikeTab